# Is it possible to combine these two ssh commands into one?

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm using bash on Mac 10.9.1.  Right now, I execute these two commands to ultimately get to the server I want access to

```
ssh me@intermediate
```

and then once logged in, I execute

```
ssh me@destination
```

It isn't possible to run "ssh me@destination" from my machine without going through the intermediate server.  Is it possible to somehow combine these two ssh commands into a single line so the result is that I'm logged in to my destination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ssh -t me@intermediate ssh destination
```

If you exchange keys between your mac and intermediate and between intermediate and destination you don't need a password.

Answer (score 3):

Take look at [Transparent Multi-hop SSH](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html).

In your example, add these lines to ssh config (usually `~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host intermediate
  User me
  HostName intermediate.example.com

Host destination
  User me
  ProxyCommand ssh -q intermediate nc -q0 destination.example.com 22
```

And then just run `ssh destination`.